# The spoiled simulator xcode 9. As a broken TV

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode9

Almost every launch of the application on any Xcode 9 simulator results in that in the screenshot:
[image]
Maybe someone encountered this problem and solved it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to switch render engine to OpenGl instead of metal

Use this command in terminal.

`defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferRendererHint 2`

(1 = Metal, 2 = force use of OpenGL, 3 = OpenGL)

Or if your gpu is HD3000 you need to use

`defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferEmulationHint 1`

Comment: After that, it does not start at all) 
https://yadi.sk/i/-HaHllQF3Nv4FS
https://yadi.sk/i/BTb3Pr-73Nv4Jp

Comment: what mac do you using?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/K4ywC7j43Nv4mM
Comrade is the same and everything is fine with him (У товарища такой же и у него все нормально :) Не хочется переустанавливать же).

Comment: then you can try defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferEmulationHint 1

Comment: I'll test some more time.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. 2 does nothing now, it was an OpenCL implementation that was removed. 0 = auto, 1 = Metal, 3 = OpenGL. This is only the blitter that copies pixels from the Simulator's OpenGL software renderer. All rendering inside the Simulator is still software (no use of GPU).

Comment: I concur. Just tried it. The performance difference on Xcode 9 is like night and day with '2' (Xcode 8 was always fine, Xcode 9 ran abysmally slow until this fix)